# PHP / MySQL: What data type to chose for encrypted passwords (bcrypt, max. 100 char)

Tags: php, mysql, hash, passwords

I use the following to **encrypt a password before storing it in a MySQL db**.

Currently I have limited the password to a length of max. 20 characters since I wasn't sure if longer passwords could cause issues here due to the encryption output.

**In PHP I use the following for the encryption:**

```
$pw = password_hash($_POST["pw"], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

The password is being trimmend on the client side before being passed on.

Can someone **tell me if** `CHAR(60)` **is enough to cover** for passwords with up to 100 characters (numbers, upper case and lower case letters, special characters) ?

**Also, is there a common max. character limit that should be set for passwords - without increasing vulnerability ?**
I learned that some people definitely want to use longer passwords like short phrases etc.

Comment: The manual's there for answers http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Thanks. So based on this I should change it to CHAR(255) and then could allow passwords up to 100 characters, is that correct ?

Comment: No it isn't.... the php docs say to use varchar(255), you don't want to use char for something like that

Comment: 1. Passwords are *hashed*, not encrypted. Learn the difference. 2. Do ***NOT*** limit the maximum length of a password. 3. Use `VARCHAR(255)` as recommended in the manual. 4. Do ***NOT*** limit the maximum length of a password.

Comment: @Sammitch: Thanks as well. I will apply. If you want to post it as an answer than I will accept it.

Comment: comments should all be used and posted as an answer **but** as a community wiki. that's what I suggest anyway. or closed using this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords or question deleted. it's been answered; in comments.

Answer (score 6):

As the name says, the function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) will calculate a hash of the password. This hash is always of the same length, regardless of the length of the password. So there is no reason to limit the length of the password, accept passwords of any length, only require a minimum length.

Currently the function will calculate a BCrypt hash, its output will always be 60 characters. A database field of `char(60)` would therefore be enough to store the hashes.

The used hash algorithm can change in future though, to cope with future threats. That's why the manual recommends to use the parameter PASSWORD_DEFAULT and a field of `varchar(255)`. This gives the function the necessary room to be future-proof.

```
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: and what about the collation? are hashed password with `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` ascii compliant? or will i need unicode?

Comment: @Anthony - The charset should never be a problem, because the generated hash-strings contain only characters form a narrow alphabet, no multibyte unicode characters and no problematic characters for SQL statements. Btw: the collation only controls the sorting of strings and is not the same as the charset.

Comment: `Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice). `